# expo FaceDetector keep triggering "onFacesDetected" event in "accurate" mode even without face

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, face-detection

I'm new to react native.
I'm using *expo* *FaceDetector* to detect faces.
when I'm using it in "*fast*" mode it trigger "*onFacesDetected*" event correctly.
But when I'm using "*accurate*" *mode* "*onFacesDetected*" event keep triggering (on "*minDetectionInterval*") (it suppose to trigger after detecting a face).

Is this a expo issue or my code is wrong ?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
1.below is fast mode code

```
    <Camera style={styles.camara} type={type}
            ref={ref}
            onFacesDetected={faceDetected}
            faceDetectorSettings={{
                mode: FaceDetector.Constants.Mode.fast,
                detectLandmarks: FaceDetector.Constants.Landmarks.all,
                 runClassifications: FaceDetector.Constants.Classifications.all,
                minDetectionInterval: 100,
                tracking: false,
              }}>
        </Camera>
```

2.below is accurate mode code

```
       <Camera style={styles.camara} type={type}
            ref={ref}
            onFacesDetected={faceDetected}
            faceDetectorSettings={{
                mode: FaceDetector.Constants.Mode.accurate,
                detectLandmarks: FaceDetector.Constants.Landmarks.all,
                 runClassifications: FaceDetector.Constants.Classifications.all,
                minDetectionInterval: 100,
                tracking: false,
              }}>
        </Camera>
```

expo documentation [expo documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/facedetector/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may help. The problem is that **onFacesDetected** returns an object, not a boolean value.

```js
const [faceDetected, setFaceDetected] = useState(false)
const checkForFace = (obj) => {
  try {
    setFaceDetected(obj.faces.length==0?false:true);
    //or
    setFaceDetected(obj.faces.length);
    //0 is false and any natural number(1,2,3...) is true
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

return (       
  <Camera style={styles.camara} type={type}
      ref={ref}
      onFacesDetected={(e)=>checkForFace(e)}
      faceDetectorSettings={{
          mode: FaceDetector.Constants.Mode.accurate,
          detectLandmarks: FaceDetector.Constants.Landmarks.all,
          runClassifications: FaceDetector.Constants.Classifications.all,
          minDetectionInterval: 500,
          tracking: true,
      }}>
  </Camera>
)
```